# Why MHE after 12 seconds runs skeptically over my model?

Tags: gekko

I am new to control systems and have tried to use GEKKO. For my model simulation geos correct and run however at MHE and also at MPC It runs correctly when t = 15 seconds after that if t = 16 seconds at the 12th it goes skeptical as shown on the attached figure. Is there a reason for that?

```py
m = GEKKO(remote = False)

g  = m.Const(value = 9.81)
Cc = m.Const(value = 2*10**-5)
D1 = m.Const(value = 0.1016)
D2 = m.Const(value = 0.1016)
h1 = m.Const(value = 100) 
hv = m.Const(value = 1000)
L1 = m.Const(value = 500)
L2 = m.Const(value = 1100)
V1 = m.Const(value = 4.054)
V2 = m.Const(value = 9.729)
A1 = m.Const(0.008107)
A2 = m.Const(0.008107)

beta1 = m.Const(value = 1.5 * 10**9)
beta2 = m.Const(value = 1.5* 10**9)
Pres = m.Const(value = 1.261 * 10**7)
M = m.Const(value = 1.992 * 10**8) 
rho = m.Const(value = 932)
PI = m.Const(value = 2.32 * 10**(-9))
visc = m.Const(value = 0.024)

fo = m.Const(value = 60)
Inp = m.Const(value = 65)
Pnp = m.Const(value = 1.625 * 10**5)

z = m.MV(1, lb = 0.1, ub = 1)

f = m.MV(35, lb = 35, ub = 65)
f.STATUS = 1
f.DMAX = 30   
f.DCOST = 0.0002 # slow down change of frequency
f.UPPER = 65

Ppin = m.CV()
Ppin.STATUS = 1 # add the SP to the objective
Ppin.SP = 6e6 # set point
Ppin.TR_INIT = 1 # set point trajectory
Ppin.TAU = 5 # time constant of trajectory

Pwf = m.Var(ub = Pres)
Ppout = m.Var()
Pwh = m.Var()
Pm = m.Var()

P_fric_drop = m.Var()
F1 = m.Var()
F2 = m.Var()

q = m.Var(lb = 0)
qc = m.Var(lb = 0)
qr = m.Var(lb = 0)

I = m.Var()
H = m.Var()
BHP = m.Var(lb = 0)
BHPo = m.Var()
qo = m.Var()
Ho = m.Var()

m.Equation([Pwh.dt() == beta2*(q-qc)/V2,
            Pwf.dt() == beta1*(qr-q)/V1,
            q.dt() == (1/M)*(Pwf - Pwh - rho*g*hv - P_fric_drop + (Ppout-Ppin))])

m.Equation([qr == PI*(Pres - Pwf),
            qc == Cc*z*(m.sqrt((Pwh - Pm))),
            Pm == Pwh/2,
            P_fric_drop == F1 + F2,
            F1 == 0.158 * rho * L1* q**2 * visc**0.5 /(D1 * A1**2 * (rho*D1*q)**0.5),
            F2 == 0.158 * rho * L2* q**2 * visc**0.5 /(D2 * A2**2 * (rho*D2*q)**0.5)])

m.Equation([
              qo == q * fo/f,
              H == Ho * (f/fo)**2,
              BHPo == -2.3599e9*qo**3 - 1.8082e7*qo**2 + 4.3346e6*qo + 9.4355e4,
              BHP == BHPo * (f/fo)**3,
              Ppin == Pwf - rho*g*h1 - F1,
              Ho == 9.5970e2+7.4959e3*qo+-1.2454e6*qo**2,
              I == Inp * BHP / Pnp,
              Ppout == H*rho*g + Ppin
             ])

m.options.solver = 1
m.options.MAX_ITER = 250   

m.options.IMODE = 1
m.solve(debug=True)

tf = 30  # final time (sec)
st = 2.0   # simulation time intervals
nt = int(tf/st)+1 # simulation time points
m.time = np.linspace(0,tf,nt)

m.options.CV_TYPE = 2 # squared error
m.options.solver = 3
m.options.NODES=2
m.options.IMODE = 5
m.solve(debug = False)
```

[image: Simulation results]

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to reproduce the problem you encountered so I'll give a few specific suggestions for troubleshooting your application and improving the ability of the solver to find a solution.

**Help the Solver Find a Solution**

- Avoid `sqrt(-negative)`

```py
#qc == Cc*z*(m.sqrt((Pwh - Pm)))
qc**2 == Cc**2 * z**2 * (Pwh - Pm) # avoid negative in sqrt
```

- Avoid potential for divide by zero. The value of `q` is constrained away from zero but look for other equations that could be improved by re-arrangement.

```py
#qo == q * fo/f
qo * f == q * fo
```

```py
#H == Ho * (f/fo)**2
H * fo**2 == Ho * f**2
```

```py
#I == Inp * BHP / Pnp
I * Pnp == Inp * BHP
```

- Constrain the FVs and MVs

It can often help to put small `DMAX` or limit the upper and lower bound for `FVs` and `MVs`. Constraints on the `Var` types can lead to infeasible solutions.

- Reduce the degrees of freedom

For MHE applications, I recommend that you use `FVs` instead of `MVs` for your unknown parameters. The `FVs` calculate a single value over all of the measurements. The `MVs` calculate a new parameter value for every time point. Using an `FV` instead of an `MV` can help the solver because there are fewer decisions for the optimizer and the parameter values won't be adjusted to track signal noise.

**Check the Solutions**

- Configure the objective function.

For MHE applications, you need to have some `CV` values that you are trying to match that have `FSTATUS=1`. In the example you posted there are no `CVs` with `FSTATUS=1` or any inserted measurements. MHE is to align a model with measured `CVs` values by adjusting the unknown parameters as `FVs` or `MVs`.

- Check the solver status to make sure that it found a successful solution with `APPSTAUTS==1`

```py
if m.options.APPSTATUS==1:
    print('Successful Solution)
else:
    print('Solver Failed to Find a Solution')
```

- Create plots of the variables, especially if there is a problematic period. You can often see where there is an integrating variable such as `qr` or `qc` that are approaching a variable constraint. Here is an example where I converted your MHE application into an MPC application. I'm adjusting the friction factor `f` (not realistic) and the valve opening `z` to show how the MPC drives `Ppin` to the target set point.

[image: MPC Results]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO(remote = False)

g  = m.Const(value = 9.81)
Cc = m.Const(value = 2*10**-5)
D1 = m.Const(value = 0.1016)
D2 = m.Const(value = 0.1016)
h1 = m.Const(value = 100) 
hv = m.Const(value = 1000)
L1 = m.Const(value = 500)
L2 = m.Const(value = 1100)
V1 = m.Const(value = 4.054)
V2 = m.Const(value = 9.729)
A1 = m.Const(0.008107)
A2 = m.Const(0.008107)

beta1 = m.Const(value = 1.5 * 10**9)
beta2 = m.Const(value = 1.5* 10**9)
Pres = m.Const(value = 1.261 * 10**7)
M = m.Const(value = 1.992 * 10**8) 
rho = m.Const(value = 932)
PI = m.Const(value = 2.32 * 10**(-9))
visc = m.Const(value = 0.024)

fo = m.Const(value = 60)
Inp = m.Const(value = 65)
Pnp = m.Const(value = 1.625 * 10**5)

z = m.MV(1, lb = 0.1, ub = 1)
z.STATUS = 1
z.DMAX = 0.01

f = m.MV(35, lb = 35, ub = 65)
f.STATUS = 1
f.DMAX = 30   
f.DCOST = 0.0002 # slow down change of frequency
f.UPPER = 65

Ppin = m.CV()
Ppin.STATUS = 1 # add the SP to the objective
Ppin.SP = 6e6 # set point
Ppin.TR_INIT = 1 # set point trajectory
Ppin.TAU = 5 # time constant of trajectory

Pwf = m.Var(ub = Pres)
Ppout = m.Var()
Pwh = m.Var()
Pm = m.Var()

P_fric_drop = m.Var()
F1 = m.Var()
F2 = m.Var()

q = m.Var(lb = 0)
qc = m.Var(lb = 0)
qr = m.Var(lb = 0)

I = m.Var()
H = m.Var()
BHP = m.Var(lb = 0)
BHPo = m.Var()
qo = m.Var()
Ho = m.Var()

m.Equation([Pwh.dt() == beta2*(q-qc)/V2,
            Pwf.dt() == beta1*(qr-q)/V1,
            M * q.dt() == Pwf - Pwh - rho*g*hv - P_fric_drop + (Ppout-Ppin)])

m.Equation([qr == PI*(Pres - Pwf),
            qc == Cc*z*(m.sqrt((Pwh - Pm))),
            Pm == Pwh/2,
            P_fric_drop == F1 + F2,
            F1 == 0.158 * rho * L1* q**2 * visc**0.5 /(D1 * A1**2 * (rho*D1*q)**0.5),
            F2 == 0.158 * rho * L2* q**2 * visc**0.5 /(D2 * A2**2 * (rho*D2*q)**0.5)])

m.Equation([
              qo * f == q * fo,
              H * fo**2 == Ho * f**2,
              BHPo == -2.3599e9*qo**3 - 1.8082e7*qo**2 + 4.3346e6*qo + 9.4355e4,
              BHP == BHPo * (f/fo)**3,
              Ppin == Pwf - rho*g*h1 - F1,
              Ho == 9.5970e2+7.4959e3*qo+-1.2454e6*qo**2,
              I * Pnp == Inp * BHP,
              Ppout == H*rho*g + Ppin
             ])

m.options.solver = 1
m.options.MAX_ITER = 250   

m.options.IMODE = 1
m.solve()

tf = 30  # final time (sec)
st = 2.0   # simulation time intervals
nt = int(tf/st)+1 # simulation time points
m.time = np.linspace(0,tf,nt)

m.options.CV_TYPE = 2 # squared error
m.options.solver = 3
m.options.NODES=2
m.options.IMODE = 6

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
for i in range(10):
    m.solve(disp=False)
    print(i,m.options.APPSTATUS)
    plt.subplot(10,1,i+1)
    plt.plot(m.time+i*st,Ppin.value)
    plt.xlim([0,50])
    plt.ylim([6e6,7e6])
plt.show()
```

Your application looks like it is for hydraulic pressure control in drilling. There are [additional models available on GitHub](https://github.com/APMonitor/drilling). I hope you'll consider contributing your model or case studies to the open-source repository.